# Add new date type?

Tags: datetime

How can I add a new date type?

Under "Date type" I have "Long", "Medium" and "Short". How can I add a new option to this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to /admin/config/regional/date-time
2. Click "Add date type"
3. Fill in the details.

If you require a different format than those available, you can add a new one at /admin/config/regional/date-time/formats.